# Circular dependencies between functions in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have seen some questions about circular dependencies in ocaml, but they were all about dependencies between *types*.

In my case, I have a function called `eval`. It simulates an interpreter for a made-up language and needs to call functions like this:

```
let rec eval e r = 
match e with
(* ... *)
    Forall(p, s) ->
        let pred = eval p r in
            let set = eval s r in
                forall pred s |
(* ... *)
```

Problem is, `forall` looks something like this:

```
let forAll (p : exp) (s : evT) : evT =
    match s with
    SetVal(Empty(_)) -> (Bool true) |
    SetVal(Set(lst, _)) ->
        match p with
                   (* irrelevant code *)
                        match l with
                            [] -> acc |
                            h::t -> aux t ((eval (FunCall(p, (evTToExp h))) env0)::acc)
                in
                    (* irrelevant code *)
```

As you can see, it both needs to *be called by* and *call* `eval`.

If I put the definition of `eval` first in my .ml file, I get `Unbound value forall`, otherwise I get `Unbound value eval`.

How do I solve this kind of dependency? How do I let ocaml know that it *will* find the definition of the missing function, somewhere else in the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutual recursion is accomplished with the `rec` and `and` keywords:

```ml
let rec eval = ...

and forAll = ...
```